# STOP Push notification after logout

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, web-push, angular-service-worker

I'm using angular in my project which user swPush. The notification works fine, but even after user1 logged out am getting the push notification. I don't want to push notification to the logged out users.After the user2 logged in both user1 and user2 getting notifications on the same device, this confuses the user. I want to restrict the user to get notification only when they logged in. How can I do achieve this. Is there any method.

I already try unregistering the service workers using

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
            for(let registration of registrations) {
                registration.unregister()
            } 
 })
```

But after using this, both the users are not getting notification.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

You should not unregister the Service Worker registrations because, well, that unregisters all of them. Unregistering Service Worker prevents any push logic from happening since web push is a layer on top of Service Workers - you need to have Service Workers registered and active in order to use push notifications, right?

You have two options if you only think about "showing the notifications":

1. When the user logs out, *stop sending* the push notifications. Of course this means that the web app logic has to inform your server somehow that now the logout event happened and precisely who it was (which of the possible different browser sessions of this particular user). Of course your server should already have information about the logout event.
2. Keep track of the logged in user in the browser (your JS code) and only show push notifications relevant to that user. You need to somehow distinquish between the receivers of the push notifications and the active user sessions in the browser and most likely handle it in `self.addEventlistener('push', ...)` in the SW.

If you think about privacy/security standpoint, the option #2 is of course wrong. If you only hide/not show the logged-out user's notifications, it means you're still sending them from the server. The notifications could include private information and whatnot.

So really you should go for #1. That's the right way to implement this. It leaks no information from the logged-out users, keeps the users' push subscriptions separate, and saves bandwidth.